# Decent ocamlfind documentation

Tags: ocaml, ocamlfind

I use ocaml with emacs tuareg mode, as a new user I don't really know much about all the ocaml tools...

Recently I installed ocaml-wlc with opam, it's a binding for wayland library in ocaml. I have tried to import the library with `open` in my code but it doesn't work.

After some research, I found that I need to use ocamlfind, the tool for managing exernal library. I haven't found any tutorial or documentation for this tool on the web, so I read the manual.

After this I still doesn't know how to use the library...

I find that there's a lot of tool for ocaml but I haven't found yet any proper tutorial/documentation about how to use that ecosystem.

The title ask about an ocamlfind tutorial, but in fact I'm looking for a decent tutorial about the ocaml tools ecosystem and how to manage simple tasks like installing and using libraries with opam.

Thank you

Comment: I wrote a blog post for just this purpose, it will get you up to speed on everything OCaml toolchain, verbiage. http://hyegar.com/blog/2015/10/19/so-you're-learning-ocaml/

Answer (score 1):

It contains an `example` directory showing how to use it:

https://github.com/Armael/ocaml-wlc/tree/master/example

In short, assuming you're using ocamlbuild, put `true: package(wlc)` in your `_tags` file.

Comment: And the tag would be used by ocaml-find in the `ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind example.native`command ?
And what will do ocaml-find ? Has opam tell him I've installed libray wlc ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ocamlfind list` to get a list of all known ocamlfind packages, respectively of their internal names.

If you have findlib activated in your toplevel (`ocaml`) then you will get hints about loading packages into the toplevel:

```
str@s132-intel:~> ocaml
        OCaml version 4.02.3

Findlib has been successfully loaded. Additional directives:
  #require "package";;      to load a package
  #list;;                   to list the available packages
  #camlp4o;;                to load camlp4 (standard syntax)
  #camlp4r;;                to load camlp4 (revised syntax)
  #predicates "p,q,...";;   to set these predicates
  Topfind.reset();;         to force that packages will be reloaded
  #thread;;                 to enable
```

To use a package in the toplevel use `#require "internalname";;` using the name shown by `#list;;`, only then you can use open.

Side note: `open Modulename` has the disadvantage to hide where the functions are coming from.

To compile your code, there is an invocation of the compiler prefixed with ocamlfind, [see ocamlfind doc here](http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/dl/findlib-1.2.5/doc/ref-html/r17.html#OCAMLFIND.OCAMLC), the general syntax is:

```
# binary test1, use modules Unix and Str, link packages in
ocamlfind ocamlc -o test1 -packages unix,str -linkpkg test1.ml
```

Hope this gets you started. See ocaml.org for more information.

And be patient, this is not a mainstream language with tons of material. But you can talk to the researchers and developers directly on their mailing lists.